# send email via hotmail in python

Tags: python, smtp, hotmail

I want to send an email from my server. I'm trying to send using a hotmail account that I already have.

```
user = "myaddress@hotmail.com"
passwd = "xxxxxxxxx"

from_addr = "myaddress@hotmail.com"
to_addr = "someaddress@gmail.com"
smtp_srv = "smtp.live.com"

subject = "Home Server Uptime"
message = "The server has been online for: %s" %(uptime)

smtp = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_srv,587)
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.starttls()
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.login(user, passwd)
smtp.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, message)
smtp.quit()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sendemail.py", line 23, in <module>
    smtp.starttls()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 636, in starttls
    (resp, reply) = self.docmd("STARTTLS")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 385, in docmd
    return self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 358, in getreply
    + str(e))
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this.

Here is the output of set_debuglevel(1) as Nathan suggested:

```
send: 'ehlo [127.0.1.1]\r\n'
reply: '250-BLU0-SMTP190.blu0.hotmail.com Hello [my-ip-address]\r\n'
reply: '250-TURN\r\n'
reply: '250-SIZE 41943040\r\n'
reply: '250-ETRN\r\n'
reply: '250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: '250-DSN\r\n'
reply: '250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: '250-8bitmime\r\n'
reply: '250-BINARYMIME\r\n'
reply: '250-CHUNKING\r\n'
reply: '250-VRFY\r\n'
reply: '250-TLS\r\n'
reply: '250-STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: '250 OK\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: BLU0-SMTP190.blu0.hotmail.com Hello [my-ip-address]
TURN
SIZE 41943040
ETRN
PIPELINING
DSN
ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
8bitmime
BINARYMIME
CHUNKING
VRFY
TLS
STARTTLS
OK
send: 'STARTTLS\r\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sendemail.py", line 24, in <module>
    smtp.starttls()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 636, in starttls
    (resp, reply) = self.docmd("STARTTLS")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 385, in docmd
    return self.getreply()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 358, in getreply
    + str(e))
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Have you tried `smtp.set_debuglevel(1)`? You might get more useful output.

Comment: Pasted the output of set_debuglevel(1) in the main post

Answer (score 17):

try this

```
import email
import smtplib

msg = email.message_from_string('warning')
msg['From'] = "example1@hotmail.fr"
msg['To'] = "example2@hotmail.fr"
msg['Subject'] = "helOoooOo"

s = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.live.com",587)
s.ehlo() # Hostname to send for this command defaults to the fully qualified domain name of the local host.
s.starttls() #Puts connection to SMTP server in TLS mode
s.ehlo()
s.login('example1@hotmail.fr', 'pass')

s.sendmail("example1@hotmail.fr", "example2@hotmail.fr", msg.as_string())

s.quit()
```

Comment: You should explain why your code is fixing the questioners problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code is failing when trying to start TLS (`smtp.starttls()`). I just tested `smtp.live.com` and I was able to get to the line in your code where you attempt to login, so it might be something due to how your network is setup.

This is unrelated, but according to the [smtplib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtp-example) docs, you have to add the `from` and `to` address headers at the beginning of the message:

```
parts = ("From: " + from_addr,
         "To: " + to_addr,
         "Subject: " + subject,
         "",
         message)    
msg = '\r\n'.join(parts)
```

Comment: Added `msg = "To:%s\nFrom:%s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s" % (to_addr, from_addr, subject, message)` and changed `smtp.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, msg)` . Still the same error :(

Comment: Its a basically a Ubuntu file server running samba connected to the router. I haven't set up any mail server or any special changes to the network. I turned the firewall down to see if that was causing the problem. Still can't authenticate with Hotmail. Able to do so via the web browser though.

Answer (score 1):

Use smtp-mail.outlook.com as mail server. I tested and it worked not smtp.live.com.Otherwise the rest of the code is fine. Although gmail does not allow sending this way.